# jquery dialog pass value to the parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

What I am trying to do is to open up jquery dialog which works just fine. it loads the content that loading on the page.make a selection click OK button and store the selection to the hidden from variable. Up until this point everything works.

Now once the dialog is closed I want to immediately trigger the event on that hidden form variable. Please advise.

so dialog is called like this

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var temp = $("#name").val();
                    var temp2 = $("#id").val();
                    $("#" + val1).val(temp);
                    $("#" + val2).val(temp2);

                        $("#hiddenID").change();


                },
                "Cancel": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");



                }
            }
        });
```

on the form

I have this

```
  $("#hiddenID").change(function(){
      //  alert($("#hiddenID").val());
         }).change();
```

Comment: So what is the problem? This should work, i.e. your change event should get called when the "OK" button is clicked. Unless you forgot to declare `val1` and `val2` in which case an exception is raised before the line `$("#hiddenID").change();` is reached.

Comment: well val1 and val2 is passed but this does not get triggered  $("#hiddenID").change(function(){
      //  alert($("#hiddenID").val());
         }).change();

Comment: Are you sure? Try commenting out the 2 lines. Also, since you have commented out the alert in your change handler, how do you know it's not called?

Comment: Even if I enable the alert I do not see the alert message

Comment: I have just copied your two snippets into a jQuery ready handler, added a line `var val1 = val2 = 'xyz';` on top, added a hidden field with id `hiddenID` and a div with id `dialog` and enabled the alert. As expected, it alerted the value two times - first on page load because of the last `change()` call, and then after clicking "Ok". I am using Firefox 8 with jQuery 1.6.2 and jQuery-UI 1.8.16.

Comment: can you post the link so i can try it too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cito/KHcXw/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

add a close function to your dialog. When it closes, it will trigger whatever you want.

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    var temp = $("#name").val();
                    var temp2 = $("#id").val();
                    $("#" + val1).val(temp);
                    $("#" + val2).val(temp2);

                        $("#hiddenID").change();


                },
                "Cancel": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");



                }
            },
          close: function(event, ui){
             //whatever you want to happen on close - regardless of how the dialog is closed
            }
        });
```